# Is there any way to add an 8-bit value to a 32-bit register in x86?

Tags: optimization, assembly, x86

Is there any way to add an 8-bit value to a 32-bit register in x86?

For example, if you do "ADD EAX,8" then the 8 will be encoded as a 32 bit value so you will have "08000000" in your binary. If you are adding by one you can use the INC instruction obviously, but is there any way to ADD a generic 8-bit value in x86 assembly?

Note I don't think you can do "ADD AL,8" because if AL already has, say, xFE in it then it will not do the carry. What about "ADC AL,8", though, will that carry the value to AH?

Comment: `ADC AL, 8` adds `8` plus the value of the carry to `AL`. It does not touch `AH`.

Comment: `ADD EAX, 8` should be encoded with 8-bit immediate. If 8 is encoded as 32 bit value, this is an assembler bug. As a workaround, you may try to use different register than `EAX`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an encoding that uses 8 bit sign-extended immediate, it's listed as `ADD r/m32, imm8` opcode `83 /0`. How you indicate you want that encoding depends on your assembler, but you have forgotten to mention which one you use. `nasm` for example automatically uses this encoding if you turn optimization on or if you explicitly ask for it like so: `add eax, byte 8`. GNU assembler seems to use the shorter encoding too, in fact I don't know how to force it to 32 bit (kind of the reverse of your problem).

Comment: Update: the NASM default these days is to enable optimization (choose the shortest encoding), because no-optimization mode is terrible.  BTW, most traditional x86 instructions (other than `mov` and `test`) that can take 32-bit immediates have an alternate opcode that takes an 8-bit immediate, so this answer applies generally, not just to `add`.  e.g. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmp